# Tensorflow Data Pipeline Generator (tf.py_function)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm training an MRI super-resolution model on about 40k volumes with Tensorflow/Keras and a custom training loop:

Pseudo python/tf code :

```
for e in epochs: 
    for s in the steps: 
        batch = data_handler.get_batch(files[s])
        model.train_on_batch(batch['lr'], batch['hr'])

def get_batch(volume_path) # online data augmentation and image degradation
    vol_hr = np.load(volume_path) # 200x200x200 array
    vol_hr = augment(vol_hr) # flips / rotation
    vol_lr = degrade(vol_hr) # blur, add noise, downsample  (100x100x200)
    batch = crop_patches(vol_lr, vol_hr)
    # batch['lr'].shape == batch_size, 32, 32, 3
    # batch['hr'].shape == batch_size, 64, 64, 3
    return batch
```

This runs terribly slow so I'm looking into optimizing the training through (i) implementing tf data pipeline (`tf.data.Dataset`) and (ii) Distributed training. This post is about optimizing the data pipeline.

My plan is to implement a tf data input pipeline (tf 2.4.1). The generator looks something like this at the moment:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import time
from skimage.transform import downscale_local_mean

def make_rand_vols(n, size=(200, 200, 200), tmp_path='./tmp/tmp_vol'):
    if not os.path.isdir(tmp_path):
        os.makedirs(tmp_path)
    rand_arr_fnames = []
    for f in range(n):
        rand_arr = np.random.rand(size[0], size[1], size[2])
        fpath = os.path.join(tmp_path, f"{f}.npy")
        np.save(fpath, rand_arr)
        rand_arr_fnames.append(fpath)
    return rand_arr_fnames


def benchmark(dataset, num_epochs=2, steps=10):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    for epoch_num in range(num_epochs):
        for s, sample in enumerate(dataset):
            # Performing a training step
            print(s)
            time.sleep(0.01)
            if s == steps - 1:
                break
            
    print("Execution time:", time.perf_counter() - start_time)


class CustomGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, fnames, batch_size=3, 
                 scale=2, shuffle=True, patch_size=32, n_channels=3):
        self.fnames = fnames
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.on_epoch_end()
        self.scale = scale
        self.lr_patch_size = patch_size
        self.hr_patch_size = patch_size * scale
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.fnames)
    
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        #'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.fnames)
            
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        vol_hr = np.load(self.fnames[idx]) # array of size e.g. (300, 300, 300)
        vol_hr = self.augment(vol_hr)
        vol_lr = self.degrade(vol_hr, self.scale) # array of size e.g. (150, 150, 300)
        batch = self.get_vol_crops(vol_lr, vol_hr) # array of size (batch_size, width / scale, length / scale, depth)
        # batch -> (batch_lr, batch_hr) -> (arr [batch_size, patch_lr, patch_lr, n_channels], arr [batch_size, patch_hr, patch_hr, n_channels])
        return batch

    def augment(self, vol):
        if np.random.randint(0, 2):
            vol = vol[:, ::-1, :] # simple for illustration
        return vol

    def degrade(self, vol_hr, downscale_factor):
        vol_lr = downscale_local_mean(vol_hr,
                                      (downscale_factor, downscale_factor, 1),
                                      cval=0)
        return vol_lr
    
    def get_vol_crops(self, vol_lr, vol_hr):
        pad = 2
        rows_lr, cols_lr, n_slices = vol_lr.shape
        lr_y_list = np.random.randint(0, rows_lr - self.lr_patch_size - 1, batch_size) #top left row lr
        lr_x_list = np.random.randint(0, cols_lr - self.lr_patch_size - 1, batch_size) # top left col lr
        z_list = np.random.randint(pad, n_slices - pad, self.batch_size)
        lr_patches, hr_patches = [], []
        for y_lr, x_lr, z in zip(lr_y_list, lr_x_list, z_list):
            slice_idxs = [z for z in range(z - n_channels // 2, z + n_channels//2 + 1)]
            # LR patch
            patch_lr = vol_lr[y_lr: y_lr + self.lr_patch_size, 
                              x_lr: x_lr + self.lr_patch_size, 
                              slice_idxs]
            print()
            lr_patches.append(patch_lr)
            # HR patch
            y_hr, x_hr = scale * y_lr, scale * x_lr
            patch_hr = vol_hr[y_hr: y_hr + self.hr_patch_size, 
                              x_hr: x_hr + self.hr_patch_size, 
                              slice_idxs]
            #print(patch_lr.shape, patch_hr.shape)
            #preview_patches(patch_lr, patch_hr)
            hr_patches.append(patch_hr)
        return np.array(lr_patches), np.array(hr_patches)

test_vol_fnames = make_rand_vols(50)    
# Make tf.data.Dataset from keras Generator
batch_size = 24
patch_size = 32
scale = 2
n_channels = 3
gen = CustomGenerator(test_vol_fnames, patch_size=patch_size, batch_size=batch_size)

benchmark(gen, steps=50)
# Execution time: 9.38716044393368

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: gen,
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
    output_shapes = ([batch_size, patch_size, patch_size, n_channels],
                     [batch_size, patch_size*scale, patch_size*scale, n_channels])
)


benchmark(dataset, steps=50)
# Execution time: 9.54540992085822

benchmark(dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE), steps=50)
# Execution time: 8.615464322036132


benchmark(
    tf.data.Dataset.range(2)
    .interleave(
        lambda _: dataset,
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE),
    steps=50
)
# Execution time: 5.204080824041739


def mapped_generator(g):
    return tf.py_function(lambda f: g,
                          inp=[f],
                          Tout=[tf.float32, tf.float32])


dataset_parallel = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: mapped_generator(gen),
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
    output_shapes=([batch_size, patch_size, patch_size, n_channels],
                  [batch_size, patch_size*scale, patch_size*scale, n_channels])
)

benchmark(
    dataset_parallel,
    steps=50
)
# NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

Is there anything I can do to make this more efficient? How can I wrap the generator inside tf.py_function?